# How to call a DialogFragment from an Activity

Tags: android, dialog

I wish to simply call a dialog fragment from an activity after clicking a button as:

```
    eventInviteDecline.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        EventInviteResponseConfirmDialog newRespond = new EventInviteResponseConfirmDialog();
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("response", "decline");
            newRespond.setArguments(args);
            newRespond.show(fm, "ok");

        }

    });
```

However, within code, it calls an error, noting: `Cannot resolve method getActivity()`.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I extended my class to FragmentActivity

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                AlertSMS userPopUp = new AlertSMS();
                userPopUp.show(fragmentManager, "sms");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is from an Activity, you should just be able to remove the `getActivity().` part and call `getFragmentManager` directly.

```
 FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not call getActivity(), when you are in activity. you can you **this.** or you can use **Activityname.this**

Its better to use support fragment manger though when using fragments

getSupportFragmentManager()